# Who choses the targets of the Exotrireme II's ability in Twilight Imperium?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

In Twilight Imperium 4th Edition, the Sardakk N'orr have a special version of the Dreadnaught called the Exotrireme.  The upgraded version of this, the Exotrireme II has the ability:

> After a round of space combat, you may destroy this unit to destroy up to 2 ships in this system.

Who chooses the targets of this ability?  The Sardakk N'orr, or the player they are fighting in combat?

Note that if the Sardakk N'orr can chose the targets, this means they can sacrifice a Dreadnought (4 cost) to kill an enemy War Sun and a Flagship (12 and 8 cost respectively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sardakk N'orr chooses the targets.

[This thread on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1845272/exotrireme-ii-self-destruct-who-picks-2-destroyed) has an official answer from FFG on the subject:

> I do have another questions about some of the "destroy abilities " in game.
>
> Exotrireme II - sacrificial ability , Assault Cannon, Yin Flagship.
> 1.) Am I correct to assume that for any Destroy ability sustain damage cannot be used ?
> 2.) Who select unit destroyed for Exotrireme II ability? Norr player or Opponent?
>
> ---
>
> Hey Fedor,
>
> Exotrireme— 1) That is correct, sustain damage cannot be used against
> abilities that ‘destroy’. 2) The N’orr player selects the units to be
> destroyed.
>
> Let me know if I can help further, –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
> Dane Beltrami Game Developer dbeltrami@fantasyflightgames.com

This is also consistent with the "Exotrireme" upgrade from 3rd edition, which read:

> At the end of a round of Space Battle, you may destroy 1 of your Dreadnoughts present to destroy 2 present enemy ships of your choice.